# Perl REST::Client best way to get and use CSRFToken and session id through cookies

Tags: perl, rest, cookies, csrf, lwp

So right now I'm using REST::Client which does a perfectly good job when it comes to making GET requests and fetching JSON data. However, the API in question, when issuing a POST request, should pass a CSRF token and session id and then if entering the right credentials through JSON should then be used further on for all POST requests.

Thing is, I see no way to fetch the cookie using REST::CLient, so I tried LWP, I was able to execute a JSON request, set up the cookie settings and still no cookies.

I tried storing it in a file, tried in a variable, still nothing

```
$mech->cookie_jar($cookies);
```

So how do I get these cookies?

P.S I'm sure the request is executed, since I'm seeing the right output and I'm seeing the cookies with a third party rest client.

EDIT:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use REST::Client;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use MIME::Base64;
use 5.010;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Cookies;

my $first = $ARGV[0];

my $username = 'user@user.com';
my $password = 'password';
my $cookies = HTTP::Cookies->new();
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( cookie_jar => $cookies );
my $headers = {Content-type => 'application/json'};
my $client = REST::Client->new( { useragent => $ua });

my $res = $client->POST('https://URL/action/?do=login', 
'{"username": "user@user.com", "password":"password"}', {"Content-type" => 'application/json'});

chkerr($client->responseCode());

print $client->responseContent();
#print $client->responseHeaders();

#$cookies->extract_cookies($res);

print "\n" . $cookies->as_string;

sub chkerr {
    my $res = shift;
    if($res eq '200') {
        print "Success\n";
    } else { print "API Call failed: $res\n";
#exit(1);
}
```

}

The code is really dirty since I've tried about 50 different things now.

The output is as follows:

```
Success
true         -> this indicated that login is successful
Set-Cookie3: __cfduid=d3507306fc7b69798730649577c267a2b1369379851; path="/";  domain=.domain.com; path_spec; expires="2019-12-23 23:50:00Z"; version=0
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/module/MCRAWFOR/REST-Client-249/lib/REST/Client.pm), it seems that `REST::Client` is using `LWP::UserAgent` internally. By default, `LWP::UserAgent` ignores cookies unless you set its `cookie_jar` attribute.

So you could do something like this (untested code):

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( cookie_jar => {} );
my $rc = REST::Client->new( { useragent => $ua } );
```

Comment: Great stuff, that's what I was looking for. However, I suspect that the way I've set it up, it just fetches the initial cookie: my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new( cookie_jar => $cookies ); Instead of the cookies after the POST request, so I'm not getting the CSRF token. How should I go about doing that, how should I get the cookies after the POST request, as now I'm getting just the regular tracking cookie. Thanks

Comment: Another thing the strange thing is that the cookie I'm getting is labeled as Set-Cookie3, doesn't that mean that there are a few before that? I though the cookie jar out was a scalar, not an array?

Comment: Please read the (documentation)[http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/HTTP-Cookies-6.01/lib/HTTP/Cookies.pm] (search for "cookie3"). The way of you have set it up ought to be correct. You are using a cookie jar. Unlike in the real world, there are cookies going into that jar when you use it.

Comment: Ok, so when I make a curl request like this curl -X POST https://URL/action/?do=login --data '{"username":"user@user.com","password":"pass"}' -c cook -H "Content-Type:application/json"
I have all the right cookies in the file, however I'm not getting all the cookies when running the perl script. Actually I'm not getting the ones after I'm authenticated, any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

While innaM's answer will work this seems  more straight forward to me:

```
$client->getUseragent()->cookie_jar({}); # empty internal cookie jar
```

This assumes you already have a `REST::Client` object in `$client`.